# Jelly Tag replace HTML Tag

Tags: html, jelly

I am trying to replace some value with a HTML tag with jelly.

But it seems that jelly doesn't like to use *greater than* or *less than* as [replacement](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jelly/libs/util/tags.html#util:replace) without any escaping.

Escaping to `&lt;` is not what I want, because in this way the HTML tag will not work anymore..

```
<util:replace new="<span>" old="replaceme" value="${somevar}" var="somevar" />
```

How do I escape a HTML-Tag e.g. like `<span>` in jelly?

Answer (score 0):

For Jelly templates (e.g. in Jenkins email-ext plugin), [it is strongly recommended](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jelly+and+XSS+prevention) to use
`<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>` on top of the jelly file, to prevent cross-site scripting vulnerabilities.

But if you need to print HTML mark up characters like '<', then wrap it with `<j:out>`. For example, here's how to disable escaping of <a> href (in a change-set message):

```
<j:out value="${changeSet.msgAnnotated}"/>
```